# First column stripe doesn't work in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have below table in an Excel 2010 file. I want to design a new table design for that from path: Design > Table Styles > New table style. Then I create one, named "Table Style 1". Then I choose second element, "First column stripe", then I format it to bold italic green color and stripe size to 4. After these I press OK and choose that new style. But no changes appear. No first column stripe is shown in the table. Any idea what is the problem please?

[image]

Comment: In "Table Style Options", did you check "Banded Columns"?

Comment: No, it's unchecked.

Comment: Check it, you configured bands should appear.

Comment: Thanks I checked it and it's showed now. But why the Total Row doesn't change to that new style format?

Comment: Total row or total column?  The stripe format or the font format?

Comment: If total column, and it's the 4th column as shown it should work.  Also check that  you do not have "Last Column" checked and configured.

Comment: For example think I add a Total row to that table. So first column stripe should also work for that, no?

Comment: No, neither the Header nor Total Row take Row or Column Stripe styling

Comment: Excuse me if I extend the topic but can you please say why when we choose a style (from light, medium or dark group), it affects on Total row?

Comment: They are independent "Table Elements" that can be styled.  They are the 8th & 9th elements available for styling.

Comment: OW yeah. Thanks again. The problem is completely solved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Stripes to take effect, you have to click the checkbox in "Table Style Options" for "Banded Columns".  Note, configurations for "Last Column" and "First Column" would override stripe configurations for those columns (where there are conflicts).